# Tengo el siguiente warning: passing argument 1 of 'gets' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c

La idea es crear un programa para guardar nombre y años de canciones es 2 distintos arreglos, apenas inicie y al tratar de compilar para seguir avanzado, y probar, me aparece el warning mencionado y no me deja avanzar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int U;

    printf("%cCu%cntas canciones va a introducir?: ",168, 160);
    scanf("%i",&U);

    char name[U];
    int year[U];

     fflush(stdin);
    for(int j = 0; j < U; j++){
    printf("\nIngrese el nombre de la canci%cn %i: ", 162, j+1);

    fflush(stdin);
    gets(name[j]);
    //fgets(name, U, stdin);
    //fflush(stdin);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < U; i++){

        printf("\nIngrese el a%co de la canci%cn %i: ", 164, 162, i+1);
        scanf("%i",&year[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Un warning no es un error. No veo cómo un warning te impide avanzar

Answer (score 2):

```
gets(name[j]);
```

La función `gets` espera recibir un puntero de tipo `char`. Tu le estás pasando `name[j]`.

Como vemos en la definición:

```
char name[U];
```

`name` es un array de caracters, luego `name[j]` es **un char**. Un puntero no es compatible con un `char` y de ahí el warning.

Tu idea es almacenar una serie de canciones junto con su año. Lo ideal aquí es crear una estructura:

```
typedef struct
{
    char nombre[200];
    int year;
} Cancion;
```

Esta estructura te permitirá crear un array con todos los elementos que necesites:

```
Cancion array[20]; // Array para 20 canciones
```

Cuando el número de canciones es dado por el usuario es preferible utilizar memoria dinámica. Por varias razones:

- Los arrays se crean en la pila del programa. La pila no es infinita y, si se llena, el programa se muere (cuidado con el tamaño del array)
- Los arrays no se pueden redimensionar (no podrías cambiar el tamaño del array  una vez creado)
- No tienes control sobre el ciclo de vida de los objetos creados en la pila (si tuvieses que compartir ese array con otras partes del código podrías tener problemas)
- Los arrays basados en variable se denominan VLA (Variable Length Array), y es una característica no soportada por el estándar de C. Tu código no es portable y en otro compilador podría o comportarse de forma diferente o, directamente, no compilar

Lo dicho, mejor usar memoria dinámica

```
Cancion * canciones = (Cancion*)malloc(U * sizeof(Cancion));
```

Un consejo: intenta dar a las variables nombres que tengan sentido. Será más sencillo leer el código y será más complicado cometer errores (como usar la variable incorrecta)